# Multiple includes in a many-to-many scenario

Tags: sequelize.js

I have defined three tables, clients, projects and users. These all have many-to-many relationships.

- A CLIENT can have multiple PROJECTS, and a PROJECT can have multiple CLIENTS
- A USER can be assigned to many CLIENTS, but also to many PROJECTS and vice versa

The join conditions are defined as:

```
Project.User = Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'project_users', unique: true, foreignKey: 'projectId' });
User.Project = User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: 'project_users', unique: true, foreignKey: 'userId' });

Client.User = Client.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'client_users', unique: true, foreignKey: 'clientId' });
User.Client = User.belongsToMany(Client, { through: 'client_users', unique: true, foreignKey: 'userId' });

Client.Project = Client.belongsToMany(Project, { through: 'client_projects', foreignKey: 'clientId', otherKey: 'projectId' });
Project.Client = Project.belongsToMany(Client, { through: 'client_projects', foreignKey: 'projectId', otherKey: 'clientId' });
```

If I am to find a list of projects a user is assigned to, I should be able to find:

- All instances where a user is directly assigned to a project
- AND I should be able to find the users assigned to a project **through a client**

I've tried various scenario's of includes with `required` flags such as this one:

```
await Project.findAll({
  //projects through a client
  include: [{
    model: Client,
    where: {
      id: clients[0].id
    },
    include: [{
      model: User,
      where: {
        id: user1.id
      },
      required: false
    }]
  }, {
    //projects by themselves
    model: User,
    where: {
      id: user1.id
    },
    required: false
  }]
})
```

Separately these work but I'm looking for a solution that can run in a single query. If my data model can be improved, I'm open to that as well